# Best method suited to store and display small image in mongo database

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, bson, gridfs

how to store small images (< 2 MB)in mongodb and display the image on webpage without downloading it?

Comment: How is *"display the image on webpage without downloading it"* supposed to work?

Comment: If one user uploads a image I will save it in database and for other users that image should be displayed

Comment: Displaying an image on a web page inevitably downloads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it as base64 image. Base64 images is represented as string. So you can easily save and retrieve it. You will encode(in front-end) and save images as string. When you retrieve it to your front-end, you will decode and display it.

Comment: I have encoded the image using Java **mime encoder**,  But while decoding the Base64 string the image is being  downloaded, any help?

Comment: What are you using for frontend? you should pass encoded image as string to frontend and decode the string there.

Comment: html, How can I show image without downloading from decoding string ?? to which data type we need to convert that string before displaying ?

Comment: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <encoded_string> >`     This is working thank you